# Remove all of x axis labels in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to remove everything on the x-axis including the labels and tick marks so that only the y-axis is labeled.  How would I do this?

In the image below I would like 'clarity' and all of the tick marks and labels removed so that just the axis line is there.

**Sample ggplot**

```
data(diamonds)
ggplot(data = diamonds, mapping = aes(x = clarity)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = cut))
```

**ggplot Chart:**

[image]

**Desired chart:**

[image]

Answer (score 729, accepted):

You have to set to `element_blank()` in `theme()` elements you need to remove

```
ggplot(data = diamonds, mapping = aes(x = clarity)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = cut))+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
```

Comment: Is there a way to just get rid of the entire axis, like `axes = FALSE` in base R. This is a lot of work.

Comment: @jtr13, you can use theme_void() to get rid of everything:
`ggplot(data = diamonds, mapping = aes(x = clarity)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = cut)) + theme_void()`

Comment: Reference: [ggplot doc](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-title-main-axis-and-legend-titles)

Comment: There is a very 'ggplot' way of doing it using `scale_x_discrete` and `labs`: `ggplot(data = diamonds, mapping = aes(x = clarity)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = cut)) + scale_x_discrete(labels = NULL, breaks = NULL) + labs(x = "")`

Comment: @WillPike +1.  A slight tweak is to use `labs(x = NULL)` to completely remove the margin used for the label.