# R remove names and order ggplot by frequency

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe `DiatomFiltered` containing the column `species`. I want to have a ggplot (ggplot2) of all species and their frequency ordered from highest to lowest. The below code works, but the names are a mess (because of way too many species names) so I want to remove that and i want the frequencies ordered. How do i do this?

```
ggplot(DiatomFiltered, aes(species)) +
  geom_bar(fill = "#0073C2FF")
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253641/order-discrete-x-scale-by-frequency-value/3256643#3256643

Comment: And for the labels see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35090883/remove-all-of-x-axis-labels-in-ggplot